# How to make Symfony 2 Crawler to accept cookies?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I am working on a crawler to crawl a listing website. I have completed the crawling and scraping part, but I have hit a road-block.

Pagination in this listing site is cookie (or session) based, so I should make my crawler to accept any cookies the website sets (sends) and behave just as a browser while making further requests.

I am new to symphony and I am not able to find any source explaining it clearly.

I found the following links while trying to find a solution. But they are not exactly what I am looking for.

http://www.webtipblog.com/creating-a-crawler-in-symfony-2-using-the-domcrawler-and-client/

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

Can anybody please tell me how can I do this?

Thank you very much.